# React Native Reanimated output value from Animated.interpolate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

i understand Animated.Code
and i get console.log in each frame

i want to know output current value from Animated.interpolate

piece from code

```
 const diffClampScrollY = Animated.diffClamp(this.props.Animation_Header_Heaght, 0, HEADER_HEIGHT)

    const headerY = Animated.interpolate(diffClampScrollY, {
        inputRange: [0, HEADER_HEIGHT],
        outputRange: [0, -HEADER_HEIGHT],
    })
render(){
   return(
    <Animated.Code>
       {() =>
         call([headerY], () => {
         console.log(headerY)
       })
    </Animated.Code>
  )
 }
```

i don't understand object from [console.log(headerY)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4oQA.jpg)

and i want to know single current value ?

Comment: Have you tried the debug node? https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-reanimated/debug.html

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Animated.Code block;

> {() => debug('headerY: ', headerY)}

The reason being that headerY is a node, therefor you cannot just log it. You have to use the special made log node in order log the node value.

Comment: when used debug 
my app is crushed and give me this message =>
expects the 'exec' prop or children to be an animated node or a function returning an animated node. Got "object" type passed to children

Comment: I can't test anything now, but just a thought, have you tried replacing only the console.log() with debug('headerY: ', headerY)? So you keep the call and everything

Answer (score 0):

`call(argsNodes, callback)` according to the reanimated [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/nodes/call/), If one of the nodes from argsNodes array updates, callback will be called in JavaScript with a list of current values of nodes from argsNodes array as the first argument.
To console the value of `headerY`, you need to pass it as a parameter of the callback function to access it like this:

```
  ...
    <Animated.Code>
       {() =>
         call([headerY], ([headerY]) => {
         console.log(headerY)
       })
    </Animated.Code>
```